# Should I thank for the documents?

Tags: email

Usually I don't answer e-mails, when a person sends me the exact documents which we previously discussed, because I think it's unnecessary blowing up of the inbox. 
But sometimes I receive e-mails in which I get a lot more documents that were discussed or someone has done more work than necessary. I feel always bad when I don't show appreciation in a follow up e-mail, because it was unexpected and spares me quite some work so I really appreciate this.
Should I change this behaviour and just leave a thank you follow up e-mail?

Comment: What is the argument for not saying thank you in the example you spelled out?

Comment: @MisterPositive There is a difference between saying and sending 'thank you'. I personally do not like if I do the arranged work in a bigger project and everytime sort out all the thank-you-emails. In my opinion it's just unnecessary and everyone in my team knows that I appreciate it, even if I don't send the follow up 'thank you' e-mail. But my question was about unexpected work that somebody put in. And like Snow saying I should change this, because it does not occur often when someone does my work, for which I am really thankful

Comment: In addition to showing appreciation, a thank you email is a means of confirming that you received the files and that they meet (or exceed) your expectations .

Answer (score 7):

Yes.  It's polite to thank people for the work they've done in sending you things.  If you put a lot of work into an email, how would you feel if you heard nothing back?

You're not blowing up people's inboxes by thanking them - you're being courteous.  You're also implicitly telling the sender that you're happy with the contents of the email (and attachments) and have no further questions at this time.